# How do linq queries and App Messages work

Tags: c#, linq

I think I need some more examples on how this whole thing in C# works. I made some but I don't think I really understand the behind the scenes.

```cs
Register<Administrator>(App.Messages.MSG_ADMIN_VIEW, admin => OpenTab("string", "string", () => new AdminView(admin)));
```

Here, why can't I just use the `getCars` select method in order to get what he hasn't chosen?

```cs
public static IEnumerable<CarV> GetCars(User user, Poll poll) 
{
    return Context.Cars
                  .Where(v => v.UserId == user.Id && v.Car.PollId == poll.Id)
                  .ToList();
}

public static IEnumerable<Car> GetCarNotChosenByUser(User user, Poll poll) 
{
    var votedCars = GetCar(user, poll).Select(v => v.Car).ToList();
    var allCarsInPoll = Context.Cars.Where(c => c.PollId == poll.Id).ToList();

    return allCarsInPoll.Except(votedCars).ToList();
}
```

Here is the copying of the car, why can't I just use new `Car = existingCar`?

```cs
var existingCar = context.Cars
    .Include(p => p.Parts)
    .Include(p => p.Participants)
    .Include(p => p.Engines)
    .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == SelectedCar.Id);
```

```cs
var newCar = new Car(Name, SelectedUser.Id , existingCar.Type, existingCar.Closed);                 
newCar.Choices = existingCar.Parts.Select(c => new Part{ Label = c.Label }).ToList();                 
newCar.Engine = existingCar.Engines.Select(c => new Engine{ Text = c.Text, Timestamp = c.Timestamp, UserId=c.UserId }).ToList();                 
newCar.Participants = existingCar.Participants.ToList();                 
context.Cars.Add(newCar);
```

```cs
public override string ToString() => Car.Name + " - " + User.FullName;
```

---

mvm

```
AdminView = new RelayCommand(() => { NotifyColleagues(App.Messages.MSG_ADMIN_VIEW, new Administrator()); });
```

Comment: It's not clear what you intend to accomplish and therefore it's not clear how to answer the question. The code that you have create a new entity using the values of an existing one, effectively creating a copy, and then adds it to the database. Note how the ID property is excluded